# Selling WordPress themes

Tags: licensing, gpl

I was wondering if I can sell a WordPress theme which is built on top of those themes that comes with  WordPress when it's downloaded

or download one for free, then modify it completely(I mean here, change the layout,  the user experience, the CSS, some JavaScript, images, icons, typography .. etc.), then resell it

Comment: What does the license say you can do?

Comment: it's distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL

This theme is free software: except as may be stated below, you can redistribute it &/or modify it under the terms of the GNU as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 2 of the License or any later version.

Comment: This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/

Comment: What do they mean by 'you can redistribute it ' ? is it the same as selling ?